# Change magento2 installation

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, installation, composer, development

I have taken over a magento 2.3.3-p1 project. Unfortunately, the installation was done by cloning the repo from github and not using composer. So all magento core modules are under app/code/magento. Do you know a clean method to install under vendor? Or is it preferable to do a clean install using composer and bring in your own customizations?

Thanks in advance.

Dev Nightmare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How to Download and Install Magento 2?

**Way 1**

Download from below link and Install
https://magento.com/tech-resources/download

---

**Way 2**

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-enterprise-edition=2.3.3-p1 <install-directory-name>

composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.4.3-p1 <install-directory-name>
```

---

**Download from github is never suggested.**

Comment: Having an installation already present with the site running in production with a dedicated server does not seem to be the correct answer. You are telling me how to install magento, but my question is different.

Comment: ok then you can install fresh magento through composer or above link and move your customization in app/code and app/design. please configure with existing database otherwise you lost all data

Comment: Then recommend to reinstall magento 2 through composer and migrate all data

Comment: Short answer : if the custom code has been made under app/code/magento too...without any kind of preference / plugin...then it's like impossible to do it. Otherwise, fresh install of clean magento as mentionned above and just add your custom code and data

Comment: yes @AndreaGregorioMastracchio

Comment: Exactly @Claims

Comment: ok thanks everybody

Comment: Hi @AndreaGregorioMastracchio one way if you have not any changes in app/code/Magento directory so you can delete folder and change the vendor path from app/etc/vendor_path.php  then download from composer.